# Callback function with function pointer through DLL with Run-Time Check Failure #0 error

Tags: c++, dll, callback, function-pointers

I had two projects which are written by C/C++. 
Project 1 output is exe file and named MyProject.
Project 2 output is dll file and named Bridge.
I try to let Bridge to execute the function in MyProject. The function seems work, but I encounter an error

**"Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call. This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention."**

I doubt that the root cause may happen in __cdecl __stdcall convention, but still don't know how to solve it. All the project's Calling convention setting are __cdecl(/Gd), and VS IDE is VS 2013.

**DLL Project (Bridge) Code**

Header

```
 typedef void(*sfcTrace)(const char *logLevel, const char *logMessage);

    class OnRequestHandler
    {
    public:
        virtual void writeLog(sfcTrace callback) = 0;
    };

    class GenericInfoHandler : public OnRequestHandler
    {
    public:

        GenericInfoHandler();
        ~GenericInfoHandler() { delete this; };
        void writeLog(sfcTrace callback);

    };

    extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) OnRequestHandler* __cdecl oneBridgeCallBack()
    {
        return new GenericInfoHandler;
    }
```

CPP

```
void GenericInfoHandler::writeLog(sfcTrace callback)
{
    const char *level = "DEBUG";
    const char *message = "TEST";
    callback(level, message);
}
```

**MyProject Source code:**

```
    typedef OnRequestHandler* (__cdecl *test)();
    HINSTANCE getDLL = LoadLibrary("Bridge.dll");

    if (!getDLL)
    {
        cout << "Cannot not load DLL." << endl;
    }

    test func = (test)::GetProcAddress(getDLL, "oneBridgeCallBack");

    if (!func)
    {
        cout << "Cannot not locate the function." << endl;
    }

    OnRequestHandler* instance = func();
    instance->writeLog(&MyProject::TestCallBack); <----- Error Occurs here
```

Function implementation in MyProject

```
void MyProject::TestCallBack(const char *level, const char *message)
{
    if (strcmp(level, "INFO") == 0){
        // do something
    }
    else if (strcmp(level, "DEBUG") == 0){
        // do something
    }

}
```

Header:

```
typedef void(MyProject::*TestCallBack)(const char *logLevel, const char *logMessage);

    class OnRequestHandler
    {
    public:
        virtual void writeLog(sfcTrace callback) = 0;
    };

    class GenericInfoHandler : public OnRequestHandler
    {
    public:

        GenericInfoHandler();
        ~GenericInfoHandler() { delete this; };
        void writeLog(sfcTrace callback);

    };
```

Comment: Might try explicitly specifying the calling convention for the call-back: `typedef void(__cdecl *sfcTrace)(const char *logLevel, const char *logMessage);`

Comment: Also: is MyProject a namespace or a class?  (I'm presuming namespace, else I would expect a compiler warning for passing a pointer-to-member function for the callback)

Comment: Thx for your comment, and MyProject  is a class. I implemented TestCallBack function in MyProject  class and passed the TestCallBack's address and let the DLL writeLog called.

Comment: Oh! then passing MyProject::TestCallBack will be your issue, unless it is a static member.  Does this not give compiler warnings?  pointer-to-member-function is a special type of pointer, and it has to be dereferenced with respect to an object, using the `->*` or `.*` operators...the object on the left serves as the `this` pointer for the method.  You can think of them as taking a secret additional parameter for the `this` pointer...I'd bet the callback is trying to clean up this extra argument that is not being passed by `GenericInfoHandler`.

Comment: I got no warnings when passing TestCallBack function address in  MyProject class. But when I am using like instance->writeLog(this->*TestCallBack), it returns C3867 Error MyProject::TestCallBack function call missing argument list; use &MyProject::TestCallBack to create a pointer to member. And C2664 Error void OnRequestHandler::writeLog(sfcTrace) cannot convert argument 1 from overloaded function type to sfcTrace

Comment: Yeah, that usage of ->* is for calling the method from a pointer-to-member-function.  That would have to be done within `GenericInfoHandler::writeLog` where you could supply the argument list.  I don't think you want to require the callback to be a pointer-to-member in `GenericInfoHandler::writeLog`, so I wrote up an alternative method below.

Comment: The declaration of OnRequestHandler::writeLog() is surely wrong.  It takes a function pointer, it is very unclear how that could be useful.  One too many.  Simply change it to `virtual void writeLog(const char *logLevel, const char *logMessage)` and now your implementation matches the declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following: (I am presuming that `MyProject::TestCallback` is not a static method, and it is it's use as a plain function that causes the stack corruption)

Update
`typedef void(*sfcTrace)(const char *logLevel, const char *logMessage);` to take an additional `void *` argument that will be supplied alongside the callback.  I.e.:

```
typedef void(*sfcTrace)(void *cb_arg, const char *logLevel, const char *logMessage);
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then update `OnRequestHandler::writeLog(sfcTrace callback)` and its overrides to take the additional argument from the caller.  I.e.,

```
virtual void OnRequestHandler::writeLog(sfcTrace callback, void *cb_arg) = 0;
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
void GenericInfoHandler::writeLog(sfcTrace callback, void *cb_arg);
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Update the implementation of writeLog to pass this new arg to the callback:

```
void GenericInfoHandler::writeLog(sfcTrace callback, void *cb_arg)
{                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    const char *level = "DEBUG";
    const char *message = "TEST";
    callback(cb_arg, level, message);
}            ^^^^^^
```

Now we can write a new non-member callback function that is capable of calling a `MyProject` object's methods, so long as a `MyProject` object is passed via `cb_arg`:

```
void myprj_method_callback(void *arg, const char *logLevel, const char *logMessage) {
    MyProject *mp = (MyProject *)arg;
    mp->TestCallBack(level, message);
}
```

Finally, we can update the call to pass the new call-back function, and argument:

```
instance->writeLog(myprj_method_callback, (void *)this);
```

As an aside, it is generally good practice on all callbacks to let the callback supplier pass an argument that will in turn be passed to the callback when it is called.  This lets the user of a callback mechanism convey the relevant data-structures to the callback function without having to store them in global variables.

Comment: Thx for your comment. I tired to use your method but got C2664 Error on instance->writeLog(myprj_method_callback, (void *)this). How did myprj_method_callback turn to sfcTrace?